# How to create a SBOM in a Java/Kotlin project using Gradle?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, github-actions, sbom

I'm working on a Java/Kotlin project using Gradle, and I need to generate a Software Bill of Materials (SBOM) that includes not only the project dependencies but also specific information like the Java version and distribution. I am currently using the CycloneDX Gradle plugin for SBOM generation, but it only lists the dependencies and doesn't include the Java environment details. I also have to make this into a Github Action for Dependabot.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.cyclonedx.bom' version '1.8.1'
}

cyclonedxBom {
    includeConfigs = ["runtimeClasspath"]
    skipConfigs = ["compileClasspath", "testCompileClasspath"]
    // other configurations...
}
```

Generated the SBOM using the `./gradlew cyclonedxBom` command.

However, the resulting SBOM lacks information about the Java version and distribution. Is there a way to include this information in the SBOM generated by CycloneDX? Or is there an alternative approach or tool I can use to create a more customized SBOM for my Java/Kotlin Gradle project?

Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The thing is: if your build produce JAR files, it means that users can use any JVM they want, so I do not see how you can include JVM information in the SBOM. Now, if you package an artifact that contains a JVM (JLink, Docker image, etc.), then it make sense to include JVM information. But in such case, Information about how the JVM is packaged might be required to answer your question.